# How to print to different ports from a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, thermal-printer

I am doing a software for managing sales at a food shop. To close the sale i want to send the order info (food and beverage) to one printer in the kitchen and the total price to another printer at the cashier which would actually be the bill..

Any clues on how to perform this trick from a rails app in a single click??

Thanks!

Comment: where are the rails app deployed,is it distributed or on single host.../?

Comment: single host. it is deplyed on heroku but i can move it to AWS if necessary..